# Winforms, WebControl, Google Maps and invalid rendering

Tags: c#, html, winforms, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

So this is another question regarding valid rendering google maps in `WinForms` `WebControl`.

There are two solutions to the problem, one of them is to add specific registry keys ([See this article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)) and another one is to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` (if you own the HTML of the displayed page) ([See this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/)).

Since we host our `google-maps` `html` and scripts files on our own servers, we can modify the `html` file. So we have tried however this causes WebControl to not render `html` file at all (gray space is displayed). On the other hand the IE works fine.

The workstation we test on has installed IE 11.

Below is our `html` file. Did we do something wrong? Anyone encountered similar behaviour? How to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <title>Mapa</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
    <!-- multiple javascript files -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var panorama;

        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            panorama = map.getStreetView();
            /* some init functions */
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for `<!-- multiple javascript files -->` and `/* some init functions */` but I had to cut these parts out. These are only `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` lines and 2 function calls in second one. If those 2 parts are really important and will lead to solve the problem I can try to post them.. somehow.

Mind that whatever we use in `content="IE=edge"` part, `edge`, or any other version number the result is the same.

Below is the screen of the `WebControl` when we use the `X-UA-Compatible`.
(Obiviously the red text is made in snipping tool ;))

[image]

Comment: You force the page to be rendered in IE8 mode: 

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`

You should edit the registry and change meta tag.

Comment: We don't want to edit the registry. Change meta tag to what? Whatever we have tried to set content value to results in exact behaviour, it works in IE, it doesn't work in WebControl.

Comment: If you don't change the registry value, WebBrowser control defaults to the old version of IE7 or IE8. These versions are not supported in Google Maps JavaScript API anymore. Please look at the discussion in the public issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9004

Comment: In the issue you have posted some people also mention the `<meta>` tag solution and it works for them. We want to stick to this as long as it is possible. The "blank page" behaviour was also described in that issue. Does `<meta>` tag is supposed to work in `WebControl` or not?

Answer (score 0):

I work with the team which created another browser component – [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser).

I think this component will be helpful for your case since it is based on the Chromium engine and should render the Google Maps without any issues.